# How to print an interval in sorted list

Tags: python, list, printing, intervals, sorting

I want to know how to print numbers which are in sorted list. The interval will be given. For example:

```
list = [5, 10, 14, 18, 20, 30, 55]
```

and our interval input is between 11 and 29. So the program must print 14, 18,20.

Answer (score 3):

You can simmply do as follows:

```
a_list = [5, 10, 14, 18, 20, 30, 55] 
print([v for v in a_list if 11 <= v <= 29])
# Prints [14, 18, 20]
```

Comment: FYI This is known as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

number_list = [5, 10, 14, 18, 20, 30, 55]

interval_list = [11,29]

result_list = []

for number in number_list:

```
     if number in range(interval_list[0], interval_list[1]):
               result_list.append(number)
```

print result_list